# Java error in Visual Studio Code "Error: Could not find or load main class App"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am fairly new to using Java in Visual Studio code, and I created a basic Java project.

```
package app;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello Java");
    }
}
```

Every time I run the program, I get that error in the output window. However, in the terminal, if I navigate to the src folder and run the following command

```
java -classpath . app.App
```

"Hello Java" gets printed in the terminal. I've spent the past few hours trying to search for what the problem might be, but I'm finding so many different possible answers, of which none worked for me. I'm thinking maybe it has to do with .classpath file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I used Java with Visual Studio code briefly a few months ago, and I did not encounter this. So I'm not sure what has changed in the past few months that I have not used Visual Studio code.

Comment: How did you create/import/open the project?

Comment: @KellyM Create Java Project in the Command Palette

Comment: Do you mean using the Eclipse New Java Project extension ( https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mellena1.eclipse-new-java-project)? If so, it should have created a .classpath file. What are the file's contents?

Comment: @KellyM I am using Visual Studio Code. Here are the contents of the .classpath file

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
        <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    </classpath>

Comment: Hmm, that is odd. Try running: `Java: Clean the Java language server workspace` in the command palette. Might also want to ensure the Java extension is up to date if you have not used it in a few months.

Comment: @KellyM apologies, I've been trying to format the code in the comment but I'm having difficulty with it

Comment: You cannot format code reasonably in comments. Don't use comments for clarification, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: after clean the workspace ,does it work ?